# Create series of counting for each employee by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count

I am trying to list out a count of how many times an employeeid shows up for each date separated by lines and in the 0000 format.
Each time the specific employeeid occurs on a specific date, the count goes up. So EmployeeId 143 happens twice on 2023-01-18, so the first row is 0001, second is 0002

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT(COUNT(e.EmployeeId), '0000') AS [Count] 
    , e.EmployeeId
    , c.CheckDate
FROM dbo.Check c
JOIN dbo.Employees e
    ON e.EmployeeId = c.CreatedBy
GROUP BY c.CheckDate, e.EmployeeId
ORDER BY c.CheckDate DESC;
```

What I'm currently getting:

| COUNT | EmployeeId | CheckDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0002 | 143 | 2023-01-18 00:00:00.000 |
| 0002 | 143 | 2023-01-17 00:00:00.000 |
| 0002 | 427 | 2023-01-17 00:00:00.000 |
| 0007 | 607 | 2023-01-17 00:00:00.000 |

What I am wanting is:

| COUNT | EmployeeId | CheckDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 143 | 2023-01-18 00:00:00.000 |
| 0002 | 143 | 2023-01-18 00:00:00.000 |
| 0001 | 143 | 2023-01-17 00:00:00.000 |
| 0002 | 143 | 2023-01-17 00:00:00.000 |
| 0001 | 427 | 2023-01-17 00:00:00.000 |
| 0002 | 427 | 2023-01-17 00:00:00.000 |

etc.

Comment: You need to provide sample data as well as desired results.

Comment: Each time the specific employeeid occurs on a specific date, the count goes up. So EmployeeId 143 happens twice on 2023-01-18, so the first row is 0001, second is 0002

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My take of your issue here is that you are aggregating while you need a window function really.

To ensure unique values for your couples <CheckDate, EmployeeId> duplicates, you can try using the `ROW_NUMBER` window function.

```
SELECT FORMAT(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                  PARTITION BY c.CheckDate, e.EmployeeId
                  ORDER     BY e.EmployeeId
             ), '0000') AS [Count]
     , e.EmployeeId
     , c.CheckDate
FROM       dbo.Check c
INNER JOIN dbo.Employees e
        ON e.EmployeeId = c.CreatedBy
ORDER     BY c.CheckDate DESC;
```

Comment: The function 'ROW_NUMBER' takes exactly 0 argument(s). error message...